# Fading out sounds when using finch in iOS

Tags: ios, openal, finch

I am using the `Finch` openAL wrapper in iOS and would like to fade out my `FISound`'s.

Suppose I have a 30 second sound, I would like to be able to fade out the sound over 5 seconds after 15 seconds for example.

I'd like to avoid dropping down to openAL for it if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up an `NSTimer` that repeatedly decreases the sound gain until zero. Or you can do it like this:

```
static const float FadeStep = 0.1;
static const NSTimeInterval FadeDelay = 0.1;

@implementation FISound

- (void) fadeOut
{
    self.gain = MAX(0, self.gain - FadeStep);
    if (self.gain > 0) {
        [self performSelector:_cmd afterDelay:FadeDelay withObject:nil];
    }
}

@end
```

This is a quick and dirty solution, but it should work fine for a lot of cases.